# How to make PCManFM default file manager in Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, nautilus, filemanager, pcmanfm

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.1` with `nautilus` file manager version `1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1`. I have installed `PCManFM 1.3.1.` What can I do to make it the default file browser?

I installed `exo-open` 0.12.11 and tried to change the default file manager via `exo-preferred-applications` to `PCManFM` but it still doesn't work.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then disable Nautilus from drawing the desktop icons by executing in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Then allow Pcmanfm to draw the desktop icons for you:

```
gsettings set org.pcmanfm.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Now execute the following command:

```
xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Edit /etc/mime.types and carefully review if nothing is left of nautilus. If it is, replace it by pcmanfm.

Reboot afterwards.

Comment: Thanks man. Could you also expand on what can I do to revert back to nautilus?

Comment: @ShihabKhan: With the same commands, replacing pcmanfm by nautilus and nautilus by pcmanfm.

Comment: It's giving me an error: No such schema “org.pcmanfm.desktop”. But PCmanFM is installed on my PC.

Comment: I tried listing all the schemas from gsettings. I couldn't find anything with "pcmanfm"